# Is there a way to load javascript files into one file to the page to optimize the site speed?

Tags: javascript, css, optimization, minify

I'm currently developing a website. Every feature works fine. However, I'm using a lot of tools to help my site more usable which provide more loads of javascript and css files so that my site performance becomes poor.

I'm searching around on the web and found some link about how to minify those script and css files. However, I would want to faster the speed by loading those files into one file and load it into the page. Thus, is there any way to do such thing?

Comment: I think putting all you code in file would make loading slower. As far as I understand, the browser opens a new connection for each file it requires for a page. So smaller file will load faster in parallel.

Comment: @UmairP: That is actually not true. A new HTTP request for every single file is much more cumbersome compared to a few more KB per file considering today´s internet connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find this a bit vague as we don't know the structure of your site; if there is any server-side technology; the markup and content of the pages, or the number and size of your JS Files (and their containing functionality). Have you ran your site through **YSlow**: http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/

These links may be helpful too:

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/19/tools-for-concatenating-and-minifying-css-and-javascript-files-in-different-development-environments/

Comment: Thanks Mike, I found a useful php library to compress js and css files. Hope it will help.